# chunksize isn't starting from first row in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Using Python 3.

I have a very large CSV file that I need to split and save to_csv. I use chunksize parameter to determine how many rows I need in both files. 
Expectation is the first code should read required rows so I can save it into first CSV file and the second should take care of remaining rows so I can save them in second CSV file:

As an example, let's say file is 3000 rows and using below code :

```
file = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv',index_col=None, header='infer', encoding='ISO-8859-1',skiprows=None, chunksize=500)
```

I've used skiprows=None as I want it to start from the beginning and chunk the first 500.

Then, second code should skip previous 500 and chunk remaining:

```
file = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv',index_col=None, header='infer', encoding='ISO-8859-1',skiprows=500, chunksize=2500)
```

However, the result I get from first code is that it always goes directly and chunk the last 500 and not starting from beginning as expected. It doesn't sound that skiprows is working as expected if chunksize will always skip to the last given number.

Would appreciate any kind of suggestion on what might be going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really need chunksize at all if I understand what you are trying to do.  Here's code that reads the first 500 lines into df1 and the rest into df2, and then combines into a single dataframe, in case you want to do that also.

```
rows = 500

df1 = pd.read_csv( 'test.csv', nrows   =rows )
df2 = pd.read_csv( 'test.csv', skiprows=rows+1, names=df1.columns )

df3 = pd.concat( [df1,df2] ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you just want to read the original file and output 2 new csv files without creating any intermediate dataframes, perhaps this is what you want?

```
names = pd.read_csv( 'test.csv', nrows = 2 ).columns   # store column names

pd.read_csv( 'test.csv', nrows    = rows                ).to_csv('foo1.csv')
pd.read_csv( 'test.csv', skiprows = rows+1, names=names ).to_csv('foo2.csv')
```

Comment: yeah, with just two chunks - this is probably a better solution!

Comment: just giving more options!  your answer was very educational to me, i didn't know how to have different chunk sizes.

Comment: Thanks @JohnE , this works well but I need to save df1 & df2 results into 2 seperate CSV files. if I do the following, it give me error : // for chunk in df1:
    chunk.to_csv('out2.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1', index=False) // produces error "'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'"

Comment: cool.  note that I just made a slight change to make sure variable names are output for the second csv, hopefully that still works the same!

Comment: Yes it does still produce the same! thanks again! this is my first question to stackoverflow and I've really liked it! I wish I posed this already 2 weeks ago :)

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you use not default (not `None`) value for [`chunksize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter `pd.read_csv` returns a `TextFileReader` iterator instead of a DataFrame. `pd.read_csv()` will try to read your CSV file in chunks (with specified chunk size):

```
reader = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=N)
for df in reader:
    # process df (chunk) here
```

So when using `chunksize` - all chunks (except the very last one) will have the same length. Using `iterator` parameter you can define how much data (`get_chunk(nrows)`) you want to read in each iteration:

```
In [66]: reader = pd.read_csv(fn, iterator=True)
```

let's read first 3 rows

```
In [67]: reader.get_chunk(3)
Out[67]:
          a         b         c
0  2.229657 -1.040086  1.295774
1  0.358098 -1.080557 -0.396338
2  0.731741 -0.690453  0.126648
```

now we'll read next 5 rows:

```
In [68]: reader.get_chunk(5)
Out[68]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.009388 -1.549381  0.913128
1 -0.256654 -0.073549 -0.171606
2  0.849934  0.305337  2.360101
3 -1.472184  0.641512 -1.301492
4 -2.302152  0.417787  0.485958
```

next 7 rows:

```
In [69]: reader.get_chunk(7)
Out[69]:
          a         b         c
0  0.492314  0.603309  0.890524
1 -0.730400  0.835873  1.313114
2  1.393865 -1.115267  1.194747
3  3.038719 -0.343875 -1.410834
4 -1.510598  0.664154 -0.996762
5 -0.528211  1.269363  0.506728
6  0.043785 -0.786499 -1.073502
```

from [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **iterator** : boolean, default False
>
> Return TextFileReader object for iteration or getting chunks with
>   get_chunk().
>
> **chunksize** : int, default None
>
> Return `TextFileReader` object for iteration. See [the IO Tools docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking)
>   for more information on `iterator` and `chunksize`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this already but it didn't give me the needed result as I get another problem when I try to save this to_csv